# RedirectTo deleting google 360 parameters from URL in Journey builder email sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

When sending emails which are built using RedirectTo, the google analytics parameter doesn't get append automatically however on links that have URL added to them directly the google analytics parameter is added automatically.

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link1)=%%" />  --- Not working

<a href="https://URL.com/es?utm_SFMCjobId=%%jobID%%&utm_SFMCsubscId=%%_subscriberkey%%" />  --- working
```

Has anyone come across this issue and if you have how did you resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a current limitation of the product hopefully will be addressed in a future release this year.